# method_getImplementation crashes on 64-bit iphone 5s

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, arm64

I have a piece of code in my project

```
- (NSData *)getIvars:(unsigned int *)count from:(id)class_name NS_RETURNS_RETAINED {
    @synchronized(self) {
        SEL selector = @selector(copyIvarList:from:);
        Method grannyMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([class_name class], selector);
        IMP grannyImp = method_getImplementation(grannyMethod);
        return grannyImp([class_name class], selector, count, [class_name class]);
    }
}

- (NSData *)copyIvarList:(unsigned int *)count from:(id)class_name NS_RETURNS_RETAINED {
    @synchronized(self) {
        Ivar *ret_val_c = class_copyIvarList([class_name class], count);
        NSData *ret_val = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:ret_val_c length:sizeof(Ivar) * *count];
        free(ret_val_c);
        return ret_val;
    }
}
```

Here's the call of first method:

```
Class class_to_anylize = [self superclass]; // some class inherieted from NSObject
unsigned int ivar_count = 0;
NSData *new_var_list = [self getIvars:&ivar_count from:class_to_anylize];
```

But it crashes at (showing no log):

```
return grannyImp([class_name class], selector, count, [class_name class]);
```

**PS:** It crashes when I include `arm64` architecture to the project's **Valid Architectures** section. But when I leave this section without `arm64` it runs without problem.

Is there any problematic code I done?

[image]

Comment: show the code of `copyIvarList:from:`, esp what is returned. BTW: This use case for this code is obviously to call a superimplementation of a method. This breaks with OOP, esp. Liskow and seems to be a code smell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is problem with the keyword `IMP`.
Actually `IMP` defines a function with the prototype:`id (*)(id, SEL, ...)`.

Under Arm64 passing arguments to a function with a variable argument count is different than how it is under Arm6 and 7

instead of `IMP` you should use exact prototype of your function.
Use this type:
`typedef NSData* (*getIvarsFunction)(id, SEL, unsigned int*, Class);`

And your code will be:

```
- (NSData *)getIvars:(unsigned int *)count from:(id)class_name NS_RETURNS_RETAINED {
    @synchronized(self) {
        SEL selector = @selector(copyIvarList:from:);
        Method grannyMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([class_name class], selector);
        getIvarsFunction grannyImp = (getIvarsFunction)method_getImplementation(grannyMethod);
        return grannyImp([class_name class], selector, count, [class_name class]);
    }
}
```

This code will work on arm6,7,64.