# aqgridview works in simulator but fail to work on the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, aqgridview

I'm currently working on a legacy code a few years ago which uses aqgridview instead of the default uicollectionview. The weird problem is everything works fine in the simulator regardless of the type of the simulator, but when I deploy it to iPad, it works only on ipad 3(and before) but does not work on iPad Air and iPad Air 2, by fail to work I mean some of the cells in the grid cell can not be clicked. Anyone has any ideas on it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered the same issue today, and I figured out it maybe have something to do with 64bit code.

Please refer to [method_getImplementation crashes on 64-bit iphone 5s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942384/method-getimplementation-crashes-on-64-bit-iphone-5s) and https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/pull/211, I just use the code from the second link to replace the implementation of - (UIView *) _basicHitTest: (CGPoint) point withEvent: (UIEvent *) event in the AQGridView.m, and it works! Hope this helps.